# Antivirus evasion for reverse tcp

Tags: exploit, antivirus, msfvenom

I'm trying to do reverse tcp in an exe payload. To do antivirus evasion, I've tried to use Veil evasion, The fat rat, and also Phantom evasion, but even if the exe wasn't deleted by antivirus (I use Avast in Windows 10), the connection doesn't start. The connection starts only if the antivirus is stopped, even if the exe isn't detected as a malicious file.

Does anyone know some methods to make a reverse tcp payload with antivirus evasion?

Comment: Have you looked into the Avast logs to see what out going connections might have been stopped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ideal way is to write a custom payload with custom behavior, you will find this [Link](https://blog.scrt.ch/2020/06/19/engineering-antivirus-evasion/) very useful

but you can try other tools like:

1. [Shell7er](https://www.shellterproject.com/)
2. [PoshC2](https://github.com/nettitude/PoshC2)
3. [Hack The World](https://github.com/stormshadow07/HackTheWorld):

for this purpose.